# Why am I getting a NOENT using Node core module 'fs'

Tags: node.js, json, fs

This a repeat question (not yet answered) but I have revised and tightened up the code. And, I have included the specific example. I am sorry to keep beating this drum, but I need help.

This is a Node API. I need to read and write JSON data. I am using the Node core module 'fs', not the npm package by the same name (or fs-extra). I have extracted the particular area of concern onto a standalone module that is shown here:

```
'use strict';

/*==================================================
    This service GETs the list of ids to the json data files 
    to be processed, from a json file with the id 'ids.json'.
    It returns and exports idsList (an array holding the ids of the json data files)
    It also calls putIdsCleared to clear the 'ids.json' file for the next batch of processing
==================================================*/

//  node modules
const fs          = require('fs');
const config      = require('config');

const scheme      = config.get('json.scheme')
const jsonPath    = config.get('json.path');
const url         = `${scheme}${jsonPath}/`;
const idsID       = 'ids.json';
const uri         = `${url}${idsID}`;
let idsList = [];

const getList = async (uri) => {
    await fs.readFile(uri, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return(console.log( new Error(err.message) ));
        }
        return jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    })
}

//  The idea is to get the empty array written back to 'ids.json' before returning to 'process.js'
const clearList = async (uri) => {
    let data = JSON.stringify({'ids': []});
    await fs.writeFile(uri, data, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return (console.log( new Error(err.message) ));
        }
        return;
    })
}

getList(uri);

clearList(uri)

console.log('end of idsList',idsList);

module.exports = idsList;
```

Here is the console output from the execution of the module:

```
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'File:///Users/doug5solas/sandbox/libertyMutual/server/api/ids.json'
        at ReadFileContext.fs.readFile [as callback] 

 (/Users/doug5solas/sandbox/libertyMutual/server/.playground/ids.js:24:33)
        at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:235:13)
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'File:///Users/doug5solas/sandbox/libertyMutual/server/api/ids.json'
        at fs.writeFile 

 (/Users/doug5solas/sandbox/libertyMutual/server/.playground/ids.js:36:34)
        at fs.js:1167:7
        at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
```

I am being told there is no such file or directory. However I can copy the uri (as shown in the error message)

```
File:///Users/doug5solas/sandbox/libertyMutual/server/api/ids.json
```

into the search bar of my browser and this is what is returned to me:

```
{
    "ids": [
        "5sM5YLnnNMN_1540338527220.json",
        "5sM5YLnnNMN_1540389571029.json",
        "6tN6ZMooONO_1540389269289.json"
    ]
}
```

This result is the expected result. I do not "get" why I can get the data manually but I cannot get it programmatically, using the same uri. What am I missing? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by going to readFileSync. I don't like it but it works and it is only one read.

Answer (score 0):

Your File URI is in the wrong format.
It shouldn't contain the `File://` protocol (that's a browser-specific thing).

I'd imagine you want `C://Users/doug5solas/sandbox/libertyMutual/server/api/ids.json`.

Comment: The reason I used "Files://..." was a desperation move because "localhost:3000/..." failed both programmatically and manually. But, I wasn't aware that "Files:///..." was browser specific, so I will change the way I construct the uri. That was a good piece of info to pick up. And, I believe 'C://...' will not work on my Mac.

Comment: Here is the result using localhost: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'localhost:3000//Users/doug5solas/sandbox/libertyMutual/server/api/ids.json'